# Hypergeometric distribution question steps

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

A firm that refurbishes personal computers (PCs) recently received 24 faulty computers
of a similar make and model. 21 PCs have been fixed but an intern mistakenly packaged all the PCs to storage without labeling. The repair engineer will need to test the PCs one after another until he identifies the 3 PCs that are not yet fixed. Find the probability that he tested 15 computers to complete the task.

I think hypergeometric distribution works over here.

Steps I have done :

The number of ways to choose 3 faulty computers out of the 24 is given by the binomial coefficient:

${24 \choose 3} = \frac{24!}{3!(24-3)!} = 2024$

The total number of ways to choose 15 computers from the 24 is:

${24 \choose 15} = \frac{24!}{15!(24-15)!} = 2,704,156$

The probability that the repair engineer tested exactly 15 computers to complete the task is the probability that he tested exactly 12 good computers and 3 faulty computers in a specific order, followed by 12 more good computers in any order. The probability of this specific sequence of events is:

Don't know further how to proceed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it took the tester $15$ tries to find all three computers, it means that two things happened:

1. The the first $14$ computers he sampled contained exactly $2$ faulty computers.
2. The $15^\text{th}$ computer he sampled was the last faulty computer.

The probability of the first event is exactly described by a hypergeometric distribution. To find the probability that a sample of $14$ computers out of $24$ contains exactly $2$ faulty computers out of $3$, you indeed use the hypergeometric distribution, which gives
$$
\frac{\binom{3}{2}\binom{21}{12}}{\binom{24}{14}}.
$$
Then, conditional on the first event occurring, the probability of the second event is $\frac1{10}$, because there are ${10}$ computers left and one of them is faulty. Therefore, the probability it took exactly $15$ tests is
$$
\frac{\binom{3}{2}\binom{21}{12}}{\binom{24}{14}}\cdot \frac1{10}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

A quicker approach may be to say that after $15$ tests there would be ${24 \choose 9}$ possibilities for the untested PCs of which ${21 \choose 9}$ would all be all fixed PCs, so the probability of he completed the task within $15$ tests is $\frac{{21 \choose 9}}{{24 \choose 9}} \approx 0.2248 $.

Similarly the probability he completed the task within $14$ tests is $\frac{{21 \choose 10}}{{24 \choose 10}} \approx 0.1798$

so the probability he completed the task with exactly $15$ tests is the difference between these, $\frac{{21 \choose 9}}{{24 \choose 9}} - \frac{{21 \choose 10}}{{24 \choose 10}} \approx 0.0450$.

Comment: Same $\frac{273}{6072}$ answer as Mike Earnest